# PDO Bind Not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to make a simple request on my database, whoever, my attempts with binding something to the query doesn't work. I tried both codes and none seems to work

```
    $query = $this->prepare("SELECT * FROM :table");
    $query->bindParam(":table", $this->table);
    $query->execute();
    return $query->fetchAll();


    $query = $this->prepare("SELECT * FROM :table");
    $query->execute(array(":table" => $this->table));
    return $query->fetchAll();
```

However, When I try to just concatenate it, it works just fine

```
    $query = $this->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $this->table);
    $query->execute();
    return $query->fetchAll();
```

Does anyone know what might be happening? What am I doing wrong? Is that any standard that I'm not aware here?
I've done something similar before and it worked fine

OBS: The `$this` reffers to this:

```
 class Db extends PDO{}
```

Comment: You can't bind identifiers. Please see the `Note` part on http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: Table and Column names cannot be replaced by parameters in PDO.